# Can we pass CLI command in user data for EC2 to auto attach and mount EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, high-availability

I am using auto-scaling with desired count as 1 for master node. In case the instance terminates, in order to maintain high availability we need to attach the same EBS volume from previously terminated instance with the newly created one.

Provided CLI is configured on my AMI, I tried each of the followings in user data however it did not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-777099d8 --instance-id $EC2_INSTANCE_ID --device /dev/sdk


#!/bin/bash
echo "aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-777099d8 --instance-id $(ec2metadata --instance-id) --device /dev/sdk" > /tmp/xyz.sh
sudo chmod 755 /tmp/xyz.sh
sudo sh /tmp/xyz.sh 2>> 


#!/bin/bash
var='ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-777099d8 --instance-id $(ec2metadata --instance-id) --device /dev/sdk'
aws "$var"


aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-777099d8 --instance-id $(ec2metadata --instance-id) --device /dev/sdk
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It probably did not work because an EBS volume can only be attached to a single instance at one time. If it did not work you should have error messages in response to the CLI commands to help you understand why it did not work so check the instance's log.

I think you should revisit your architecture a bit because trying to do this sends up a red flag for me. First, a HA architecture should not have a single instance running. A good architecture would remain HA as instances are scaled up and down. If you have data that needs to be available to more than one instance then you should use S3 or EFS to store that data and not an EBS volume.